# WPF UIElement refresh bug?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, uielement

I have a custom panel, which is used to draw selection effect; but sometimes it does't clear the previous rectangles, if the mouse is moved back and forth when the screen is big enough（across two monitors), is it a WPF bug or limitation? Do you know how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

The simplified code looks like the following

```
public class CustomPanel : Panel
{
    private Rectangle _rectangle;

    public CustomPanel()
    {
        this._rectangle = new Rectangle();
        this._rectangle.StrokeThickness = 3;
        this._rectangle.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(220, 0, 0, 0)); ;
        this.Children.Add(this._rectangle);
    }            

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        this._rectangle.Measure(availableSize);
        return this._rectangle.DesiredSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        if (!finalSize.IsEmpty)
        {
            this._rectangle.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), finalSize));
        }
        return finalSize;
    }
}
```

and I put it in a grid and invalidate it during mouse move, like this

```
 void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var point = e.GetPosition(this);
        var size = new Size(point.X>=0? point.X:0, point.Y>=0? point.Y:0);
        this.Selection.Measure(size);
        this.Selection.Arrange(new Rect(size));

    }
```

and the result looks like the following picture
[image]

Comment: I mean, that rectangle will be used to draw selection borders. we have a very complex control and use the similar code with above to draw the selection borders, does it make sense?

Comment: Two code smells: mousemove is not calling the base implementation and mousemove is not supposed to be one of the wpf methods that invalidate the layout. Try to invalidate the layout manually in mousemove after you change Selection. (InvalidateVisual())

Answer (score 1):

try `UIElement.InvalidateVisual();`